# My app is showing a blank page all of a sudden

Tags: facebook

Our app just randomly started not loading on facebook. You application server is still up, so it looks like Facebook is blocking us out.  We get a blank white page, its an old app that hasnt been updated in a long time so I'm not sure if something has changed on the platform today.

I'm also getting a blank page when I try and load the Facebook Developer page which is new.

Anyone have any ideas what might be happening? Thanks in advance!

http://apps.facebook.com/vdreamracing/

Comment: You're the second person I've seen just now posting about this.  Something must have changed today... have you checking http://developers.facebook.com/apps to see if it gives any errors?

Comment: The Facebook platform is famous for changing all the time, so that's probably the most likely answer.

Comment: Thanks Coulton, developers.facebook.com/apps works for me so i can look at my app, but nothing in my app settings has changed.  If anyone else has had this issue today, were you able to get to the bottom of it?!

Answer (score 0):

red ellipses says the reason: you don't set up secure canvas url.

[image]

Comment: Hi moguzalp, thanks for the info.  since then I have added a secure url.  I'm unable to reproduce the screen that you are seeing right now.  Did you have to do anything special to get that error page?  Are you on any specific browser?  I still get a blank screen every time.  thanks!